# Real Time Chat Sendbird JS SDK. But the websocket connection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, sendbird

I am building an angular chat application using Sendbird.
I followed this [build an angular chat app using sendbird](https://sendbird.com/developer/tutorials/how-to-build-an-angular-chat-app)
Please refer to the above link first.

After establishing a Connection I am getting an Error while connecting using WebSocket Connection.
But even after getting errors, I can get the Last Message but,
the messages and groups are not getting updated.

Sending the component file below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import SendBird from 'sendbird';
import { ChatsService } from './services/chats.service';
import SendBird, { GroupChannelCollection } from 'sendbird';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chats',
  templateUrl: './chats.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chats.component.scss'],
})
export class ChatsComponent implements OnInit {
  userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDataIA') || '{}');
  userId = this.userData.User.Id.toString();
  chatBox = false;
  callback: any;
  OpenChannel: any;
  GroupChannel: any;
  connected = false;
  startConversationResult: string;

  conversations: Array<SendBird.GroupChannel> | any | null;
  listConversationsResult: string | null;

  selectedChannel: any;
  messages: any;
  textMessage: any;
  currentDate: Date = new Date();
  usersList: any;
  OtherUserId: any;
  sb: SendBird.SendBirdInstance;
  constructor(
    private chatsService: ChatsService
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.chatsService.init();
    await this.connect();
    this.getMyConversations();
    this.registerEventHandlers();
    this.getUsers();
  }

  ContactsConversations:any = [
  ];

  getSendBirdConfig() {
    this.chatsService.sendBirdConfig().subscribe({
      next: ((response) => {
        if (response['Status'] === 'Success') {
          this.chatsService.APP_ID = response['Data'].AppId;
          this.chatsService.api_token = response['Data'].ApiToken;
        }
        if (response['Status'] === 'Error') {
          if (response['ErrorCode'] === 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR') {
              console.log(error);
            return;
          }
        }
      })
    });
  }

  async connect() {
    await this.chatsService.connect(
      this.userId,
      (user: any,error: any ) => {
        console.log(user,error);
        if(user) {
          this.connected = true;
          this.registerEventHandlers();
          console.log(this.connected, 'connected');
        }
      }
    );
  }

  registerEventHandlers() {
    this.chatsService.registerEventHandlers(
      '123',
      (data: { event: string; data: any }) => {
        console.log('New event: ' + data.event, data.data);
        if (this.selectedChannel) {
          if (data.event == 'onMessageReceived' && this.messages) {
            if (data.data.channel.url == this.selectedChannel.url) {
              this.messages.push(data.data.message);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getUsers(){
    const userListQuery = this.chatsService.sb.createApplicationUserListQuery();
    userListQuery.next((users, error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving user list:', error);
      } else {
        // Users retrieved successfully
        this.usersList = users;
        console.log('User list:', this.usersList);
      }
    });
  }
  
  startConversation() {
    const channelName = 'Demo Channel';
    const userIds = [this.userId, this.OtherUserId];
    this.chatsService.createGroupChannel(
      channelName,
      userIds,
      (error: SendBird.SendBirdError, groupChannel: SendBird.GroupChannel) => {
        if (error) {
          this.startConversationResult = 'Error creating the conversation';
        } else {
          this.startConversationResult = 'Conversation created';
          this.getMyConversations();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getMyConversations() {
    this.chatsService.getMyGroupChannels(
      (
        error: SendBird.SendBirdError,
        groupChannels: Array<SendBird.GroupChannel>
      ) => {
        if (error) {
          this.listConversationsResult = 'Unable to get your conversations';
          console.log(this.listConversationsResult);
        } else {
          this.conversations = groupChannels;
          console.log(this.conversations);
          this.getMessages(this.selectedChannel);
        }
      }
    );
    console.log('Getting Conversations');
  }

  onUserClick() {
    this.getMessages(this.selectedChannel);
    this.chatBox = true;
  }

  getMessages(channel: SendBird.GroupChannel) {
    this.selectedChannel = channel;
    this.chatsService.getMessagesFromChannel(
      channel,
      (
        error: SendBird.SendBirdError,
        messages: Array<
          SendBird.UserMessage | SendBird.FileMessage | SendBird.AdminMessage
        >
      ) => {
        if (!error) {
          this.messages = messages;
        }
      }
    );
  }


  sendMessage() {
    this.chatsService.sendMessage(
      this.selectedChannel,
      this.textMessage,
      (error: SendBird.SendBirdError, userMessage: SendBird.UserMessage) => {
        this.getMessages(this.selectedChannel);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The Service File Looks Like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import SendBird from 'sendbird';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ChatsService {
  public sb: SendBird.SendBirdInstance;
  api_token: string;
  APP_ID: string;
  BASE_URL = environment.API_URL;
  Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') || '');
  Token = this.Data.AuthToken;
  entityId: any = localStorage.getItem('entity');
  options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('authorization', `BEARER ${this.Token}`) };

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }


  sendBirdConfig() {
    const API_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}send-bird/configs`;
    return this.httpClient.get(API_URL, this.options).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        this.APP_ID = data.Data.AppId;
        this.api_token = data.Data.ApiToken;
        return data;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    );
  }

  init() {
    this.sb = new SendBird({ appId: this.APP_ID });
    SendBird.setLogLevel(SendBird.LogLevel.ERROR);
  }

  connect(userId: any, callback: any) {
    this.sb.connect(userId, (user: any, error: any) => {
      callback(user, error);
    });
  }

  isConnected() {
    return this.sb && this.sb.currentUser && this.sb.currentUser.userId;
  }

  getConnectedUser() {
    return this.sb && this.sb.currentUser ? this.sb.currentUser : null;
  }

  registerEventHandlers(UNIQUE_HANDLER_ID: string, callback: any) {
    const channelHandler = new this.sb.ChannelHandler();

    channelHandler.onMessageReceived = (channel: any, message: any) => {
      console.log('received Message');
      callback({
        event: 'onMessageReceived',
        data: {
          channel,
          message,
        },
      });
    };
    channelHandler.onMentionReceived= (channel: any, message: any) => {
      console.log('received Mention');
      callback({
        event: 'onMentionReceived',
        data: {
          channel,
          message,
        },
      });
    };
    channelHandler.onTypingStatusUpdated = (channel: any) => {
      console.log('Typing Status');
      callback({
        event: 'onTypingStatusUpdated',
        data: {
          channel
        },
      });
    };
    channelHandler.onUserEntered = (channel: any, user: any) => {
      console.log('User Entered');
      callback({
        event: 'onUserEntered',
        data: {
          channel,
          user,
        },
      });
    };
    channelHandler.onUserJoined = (channel: any, user: any) => {
      console.log('User Joined');
      callback({
        event: 'onUserJoined',
        data: {
          channel,
          user,
        },
      });
    };
    channelHandler.onUserLeft = (channel: any, user: any) => {
      console.log('User Left');
      callback({
        event: 'onUserLeft',
        data: {
          channel,
          user,
        },
      });
    };
  }

  createUser(userId: string, nickname: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sb.connect(userId, (user, error) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } 
      });
    });
  }
  
  createGroupChannel(
    channelName: string,
    userIds: Array<string>,
    callback: any
  ) {
    const params = new this.sb.GroupChannelParams();
    // params.addUserIds();
    params.addUserIds(userIds);
    params.name = channelName;
    this.sb.GroupChannel.createChannel(
      params,
      (groupChannel: SendBird.GroupChannel, error: SendBird.SendBirdError) => {
        callback(error, groupChannel);
      }
    );
  }

  getMyGroupChannels(callback: any) {
    const listQuery = this.sb.GroupChannel.createMyGroupChannelListQuery();
    listQuery.includeEmpty = true;
    listQuery.memberStateFilter = 'joined_only';
    listQuery.order = 'latest_last_message';
    listQuery.limit = 15; // The value of pagination limit could be set up to 100.
    if (listQuery.hasNext) {
      listQuery.next((groupChannels: any, error: any) => {
        callback(error, groupChannels);
      });
    }
  }

  getMessagesFromChannel(groupChannel: SendBird.GroupChannel, callback: any) {
    const listQuery = groupChannel.createPreviousMessageListQuery();
    listQuery.limit = 10;
    listQuery.includeMetaArray = true;
    // Retrieving previous messages.
    listQuery.load((messages, error) => {
      callback(error, messages);
    });
  }

  sendMessage(
    channel: SendBird.GroupChannel | SendBird.OpenChannel,
    message: string,
    callback: any
  ) {
    const params = new this.sb.UserMessageParams();
    params.message = message;
    channel.sendUserMessage(params, (userMessage, error) => {
      callback(error, userMessage);
    });
  }
}
```

I am getting all the relevant data by calling the functions but can not get the values dynamically, i.e. for every new message/group I have to refresh my page and call the APIs again.
It should work as any other real-time chat application works.
I am having problems using Event Handler and using the Websocket connection.
Please review it.